# UIKitView in Flutter Stretching on Scrolling Up

Tags: ios, flutter, scroll, flutter-platform-channel, platformview

I'm working with `UIKitView` in a Flutter app, where I integrate a native view from third-party Android and iOS SDKs. On iOS, the `UIKitView` loads correctly, but I encounter a visual glitch when it's scrolled within a `SingleChildScrollView` or `ListView`. As the `UIKitView` widget touches the top of the screen, it starts stretching upward before scrolling continues. Notably, this issue does not occur with `AndroidView`.

Here's how I'm implementing `MyWidget` in Flutter:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  const String viewType = 'MyNativeWidget';
  Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
  creationParams['testId'] = widget.valueKey;

  switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
    case TargetPlatform.android:
      return SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 125,
        child: AndroidView(
          viewType: viewType,
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          creationParams: creationParams,
          creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
        ),
      );

    case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      return SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 125,
        child: UiKitView(
          viewType: viewType,
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          creationParams: creationParams,
          creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
        ),
      );
    default:
      throw UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform view');
  }
}
```

Usage in the app:

```dart
MyWidget(valueKey: "native1"),
```

And the corresponding Swift code for the `FlutterPlatformView`:

```swift
import Flutter
import UIKit
import TestSDK

class FlutterMyWidget: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    
    private var channel: FlutterBasicMessageChannel?
    private var myView: MyWidget?

    init(frame: CGRect, viewId: Int64, args: Any?, registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        super.init()
        // Initialization logic here...
    }

    func view() -> UIView {
        return myView ?? UIView()
    }
    
}

class MyWidgetFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    
    private let registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar

    init(registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        self.registrar = registrar
    }

    func create(withFrame frame: CGRect, viewIdentifier viewId: Int64, arguments args: Any?) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return FlutterMyWidget(frame: frame, viewId: viewId, args: args, registrar: registrar)
    }

    func createArgsCodec() -> FlutterMessageCodec & NSObjectProtocol {
        return FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance()
    }
}
```

This problem does not occur in the native iOS SDK or in a similar React Native wrapper I've built. How can I prevent `UiKitView` from stretching when it hits the top boundary during a scroll in Flutter?